# Upload de arquivo com post

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

Na minha view tem esse campo:

```
<form class="form-horizontal"method="post" action="<?=base_url('index.php/home/cadastro')?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="img" name="img" class="input-file" type="file">
```

No meu controller tenho o seguinte:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MY_Controller {

public function index()
{
$this->load->view('v_home');
}

public function cadastro()
{
$titulo = $this->input->post('titulo');
        $texto = $this->input->post('texto');
        $link = $this->input->post('link');
        $nome_link = $this->input->post('nome_link');
        $img = $this->input->post('img');


        $dados =  array(
            'titulo' => $titulo,
            'texto' =>  $texto,
            'link' => $link,
            'nome_link' => $nome_link,
            'img' => $img,          
            'data' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
            );

//print_r($dados);
        $this->load->model('noticia_model');
$casdatro = $this->noticia_model->cadastrar_noticia($dados);

        if($casdatro){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', 'Cadastro realizado com sucesso');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('mensagem', 'Erro no cadastro');
        }

        //redirect(base_url('cadastrar_view'));


    }


public function cadastrar()
{
$this->load->view('cadastrar_view');
}


}
```

Só que `$img = $this->input->post('img');` não está pegando a imegem

Alguém ajuda?

Comment: tenta usando $_FILE['img']

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Upload de imagens em CodeIgniter](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74542/upload-de-imagens-em-codeigniter)

Comment: NO CI, você não vai conseguir fazer upload dessa forma, nem com file, nem com post, você só vai conseguir usando a biblioteca de upload dele, hoje postaram uma dúvida também a respeito, veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/erro-voc%C3%AA-n%C3%A3o-selecionou-o-arquivo-para-fazer-upload-codeigniter

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Campos do tipo `file` não são pegos pelo `$_POST` (php puro) ou `input->post()` (do codeginiter) mas pela lib capenga que vem com o framework ou o `$_FILES`

```
//configuração do formato, tipo e tamanho do upload
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size']             = 100;
$config['max_width']            = 1024;
$config['max_height']           = 768;

//Carrega a lib com a configuração passada em $config
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

//verifica se ocorreu um erro.
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('img')){
  echo $this->upload->display_errors());
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado. vou testar aqui.

Comment: tentei fazer mas tá me trazendo a seguinte informação:

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /admnoticias/uploadfile/upload was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.9 (Fedora) Server at www.cairu.br Port 80

Comment: @web_charles sua pasta de upload está na raiz do projeto? o caminho a ser passado deve ser relativo a raiz do projeto.